# how to remove position absolute with jquery?

Tags: jquery

I'm using a plugin for image scroll but now I don't need that scrolling so I wanted stop that and I found when using firebug there is the following code for the div which is scrolling

```
element.style {
    left: -1256px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

And if I remove that `position: absolute;` this will not scroll. So I would like to remove that position so I tried this

```
$('#myselector div').css('position','relative'); //even tried !important
```

but not working. So how could I force to set its position to relative?

---

Also if possible I would like to change the position of which absolute is defined within #myselector to relative.

---

my html markup is something like this

```
<div id="myselector">
   <div>
    <div>
     <div>
       <div style="position: absolute; left: -{changing value};">
         <images/>
      </div>
       <div style="position: absolute; left: -{changing value};">
         <images/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is it inside $(document).ready(function() { ... }); ...?

Comment: can you show your html as well...?

Comment: question is updated, you can also see it in live of #banner-footer but I've not applied this jquery I'm just testing locally [site](http://nepotech.com/kldugar)

Comment: works fine:: http://jsfiddle.net/Xb7qH/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with just css

```
#myslector div{
    position: static !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change that attribute with

```
$(object).css({position: 'absolute'});
```

For instance:
You could use jQuery's methods .position() or .offset() to set "top" and "left" css attribute aswell, that way your object should stay at it's position changing from relative -> absolute.

I don't think that works vice versa.

demo code: http://jsbin.com/uvoka

Also try this : `$('#myselector').css('position','relative', 'important');`

Comment: $('#myselector').css('position','relative', 'important');

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$('#myselector div').css('position','relative', 'important');
```

use `important` without `!`.

Or you can try something like this:
CSS:

```
.override {
   position: relative !important;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('#myselector div').addClass('override');
```